# Is Address field mandatory for PayPal Pro when we use MasterCard?

Tags: php, paypal

I am working in a `PHP` Website. In my website I am using `PayPal pro` as the payment gateway.While integrating i have given `name,account number,CVV,Expiry Date and Card Type (Visa,MasterCard,Discover)` as fields to be entered before payment. The payment from `Mastercard` is showing error while others have no issues. I checked the card details, but the details are correct. When i searched some told that Address field is needed for MasterCard payment using PayPal Pro.

> Is address field mandatory for PayPal Pro when using MasterCard?

Comment: can you post the api request/response?

Comment: i am getting the `error code :10527` for master card. But the card details entered are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using PayPal pro we want to provide the address details.Otherwise some cards will give pending response mainly Master Card.As PayPal pro is working from website not from PayPal site this extra security is given to authenticate the cards.